# Use of global variable not working within .each function

Tags: jquery

Here is my script I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var autoFlip = true;
        $(document).on('click', '.cardFlip', function () {
            $(this).closest('.flip-container').toggleClass('flip');
        });

        $("#auto_flip").change(function () {
            if (autoFlip) {
                autoFlip = false;
            }
            else {
                autoflip = true;
            }
        });

        // only flip the containers given the autoFlip class
        $(".autoFlip").each(function (i) {
            if (autoFlip) {
                var el = $(this);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    setInterval(function () {
                        el.closest('.flip-container').toggleClass('flip');
                    }, 5000);
                }, 500 * i);
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

By default I have 4 boxes on my dashboard that automatically flip to reveal different content every 60 seconds.  I'm trying to add a button that can turn this off for those users who wish to manually flip them.

However setting up my global `autoFlip` and setting it to `false` via a `click` `#auto_flip` doesn't work.  The variable is correctly set to `false`.  but the flip keeps happening.  Any idea why the `.each` is not caring if the autoFlip variable is changed?

Here is my button that i set to maketh variable false.

```
<input id="auto_flip" class="auto_flip" type="checkbox" checked data-on="Auto
Flip On" data-off="Auto Flip Off" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="primary">
```

Comment: start by changing autoflip to camelcase on the line after the else statement.

Comment: Could you create a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @Abhi I can if it's necessary, I was just hoping I made a small little goof.   I would have done a fiddle from the beginning but I'd have to rip out a lot of it, since it uses a lot of partials etc.

Comment: @JamesWilson Hope you already go you fix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're testing `autoFlip` when you start the timer, not when the timer code runs.

```
    $(".autoFlip").each(function (i) {
        var el = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            setInterval(function () {
                if (autoFlip) {
                    el.closest('.flip-container').toggleClass('flip');
                }, 5000);
            }, 500 * i);
        }
    });
```

Also, your code to switch `autoFlip` can be simplified to:

```
autoFlip = !autoFlip;
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work, tho turning it back on is causing me an issue, but I think I can work through that.  Also thanks for the !autoFlip, never knew about that.

Comment: If you use my code to toggle `autoFlip` it should work. Otherwise you need to fix the typo that @Karan noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Typo here

```
else {
            autoflip = true;
        }
```

change it to

```
else {
            autoFlip = true;
        }
```

Comment: This is true, but it's not related to the problem, which is when he tries to set it to `false`. He doesn't have a typo there.

Comment: @Barmar I see. Thanks.